# what would be the simplest way of reading about 50+ gpio inputs?(momentary buttons)

Tags: gpio, input-device

Just need the 1/0 (pushed or not) entry. It's for a bigger projects so its gonna have a few outputs as well(not as many though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest would be to buy 4 MCP23017 I2C port expanders.  Each one provides an additional 16 gpios and up to 8 may be connected to the Pi's I2C bus.

E.g. http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/electronic-components/misc-ic/mcp23017-16bit-port-expander

Answer (score 0):

you can use i2c bus expander.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c

http://raspi.tv/2013/using-the-mcp23017-port-expander-with-wiringpi2-to-give-you-16-new-gpio-ports-part-3

Comment: The Adafruit article is several years out of date so be careful if you follow its advice.  In particular I would suggest not using Occidentalis unless you have no other choice.